# How do I solve this infinite limit with the help of Taylor/Maclaurin series expansion?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

I'm currently stuck on solving this limit in my calculus course.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty } x(\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2}-\sqrt{x^2+2x-3})$$

We are currently reading about Taylor and Maclaurin series, so I'm assuming that the solution should be based on that. I've tried to use the standard expressions $(1+x)^{\alpha}$ and also tried to simplify and re-write the expression within the root-signs, but to no success. If anyone has the time to help me with this I would be most grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $x=\frac 1y$ and work around $y=0$

Comment: You can avoid MacLaurin formula by applying $a^6-b^6=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^5a^{5-k}b^k$ with $a=\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2},$ $b=\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x \to \infty$,
\begin{align}
(x^3+3x^2)^{1/3} &=  (x^3)^{1/3}\left(1+\frac{3}{x}\right)^{1/3}
= x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2} +O(x^{-3})\right) \\ &= x+1-\frac{1}{x} +O(x^{-2})
\\
\left(x^2+2x-3\right)^{1/2} &= (x^2)^{1/2}\left(1+\frac{2}{x}-\frac{3}{x^2}\right)^{1/2} = x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{x^2}+O(x^{-3})\right)
\\ &=x+1-\frac{2}{x}+O(x^{-2})
\\
(x^3+3x^2)^{1/3}&-\left(x^2+2x-3\right)^{1/2} = \frac{1}{x}+O(x^{-2})
\\
x\big((x^3+3x^2)^{1/3}&-\left(x^2+2x-3\right)^{1/2}\big) = 1+O(x^{-1})
\\
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\big((x^3+3x^2)^{1/3}&-\left(x^2+2x-3\right)^{1/2}\big) =1 .
\end{align}

I used the two Maclaurin series
$$
(1+t)^{1/3} = 1+\frac{1}{3}t -\frac{1}{9}t^2+\dots
\\
(1+2t-3t^3)^{1/2} = 1 +t-2t^2+\dots
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't quite get the second Maclaurin series but I just used the first series on the second equation (with $t=1+2/x-3/x^2$) as well, and that worked out!

Also, am I wrong when I believe that the second equation should be $=x+1-2/x+O(x^{-1})$?

Answer (score 2):

You can expand your limit around $x \to \infty$ using a [laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series). This gives you the following.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty } x(\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2}-\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}) = \lim_{x \to \infty } (1-\frac{1}{3x}+\frac{2}{3x^2}-\frac{2}{3x^3}+\frac{8}{9x^4}+...)$$

Of course this limit is much simpler to solve as you can decompose it into limits as

$$\lim_{x \to \infty } (1)-\lim_{x \to \infty } (\frac{1}{3x})+\lim_{x \to \infty } (\frac{2}{3x^2})-\lim_{x \to \infty } (\frac{2}{3x^3})+\lim_{x \to \infty } (\frac{8}{9x^4})+...$$

They all converge to $0$ except for the first one of course

$$\lim_{x \to \infty } (1) = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x>0$, then$$x\left(\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2}-\sqrt{x^2+2x-3}\right)=x^2\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac3x}-\sqrt{1+\frac2x-\frac3{x^2}}\right).$$Now, let $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{1+3x}-\sqrt{1+2x-3x^2}$ ($x>0$). Then your limit is equal to $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$. But $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2$. Therefore, the Taylor polynomial of order $2$ of $f$ at $0$ is $P_{f,2,0}(x)=x^2\left(=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2\right)$. But a general property of Taylor polynomials is this: if $P_{g,n,a}$ is the Taylor polynomial of order $n$ of the function $g$ at $a$, then$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-P_{g,n,a}(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0.$$In particular,$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-x^2}{x^2}=0.$$But this is the same thing as asserting that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=1$. In other words, your limit is equal to $1$.

Comment: Well, since the OP is pretty new to Taylor series, I believe a little more elaboration would do him good

Comment: @insipidintegrator I have edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution! Take my upvote, but with a very tiny edit :D